# logging error messages in a log file for the client using a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

My application is a Mvc4 web application
I am reading an excel file which might have 20,000 records
The loop will go thorough the entire excel file and add all lines with errors to the string builder  object which the user should be able to correct later in a file.
My users want this displayed in a text file like a logfile which they can see right away. I am displaying this in a div right now but are scared that this might be tough when
they encounter a lot of errors

Que: How can i log all these errors in a text file that my users can click on and view the lines with errors on the client.

Please note that multiple users can use this web application.

```
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int rowNumber = startRow + 1; rowNumber <= currentWorkSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
                            // read each row from the start of the data (start row + 1 header row) to the end of the spreadsheet.
                    {

                        try
                        {

                            object col1Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value;
                            object col2Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].Value;
                            object col3Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].Value;
                            object col4Value = currentWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].Value;

                            if ((col1Value != null && col2Value != null))
                            {
                                exampleDataList.Add(new PersonalData
                                {
                                    firstname = col1Value.ToString(),
                                    lastname = col2Value.ToString(),
                                    currentDate = col3Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(col3Value),
                                    mySalary = col4Value == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(col4Value)
                                });
                            }

                        }      
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                             //log exception here
                            sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}{2}",rowNumber, e.Message, Environment.NewLine);           
                        }
                    } 

                    //convert the StringBuilder into the final string object
                    string allMessages = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like Log4Net would be sufficient for your needs. In the end you could even provide a UI to handle these problematic entries in your application.

So why not store them in your db and then show them in a custom UI where users can handle the issues one by one in a collaborative manner?